# Formula to add number of items from two separate lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Row A has items and Row B has the total for those items.

Row D has items and Row E has the total for those items.

Row G has all the items from the Rows A and D with duplications removed. I need help with the formula to add the totals in Row H.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the results of two `SUMIF` expressions. Like this:

```
=SUMIF($A1:$A5,$G1,$B1:$B5)+SUMIF($D1:$D4,$G1,$E1:$E4)
```